# Why do the end and flush parameters affect how quickly python prints to the console?

Tags: python, io

I noticed that when using `print()`, these parameters significantly affected how quickly it got to the VSCode console, in ways that I do not understand.

I used `time.time` to time some for loops counting to 100,000 with different parameters.

No end character specified, `flush=false`: 13.01 s

No end character specified, `flush=true`: 13.97 s

Why did this take longer than with the buffer? It seems like without the middleman it should go faster.

`End=" "`, `flush=false`: 0.47 s
This seems like it would be the same as the first case, but printing a space instead of a newline character, does the newline character take that long to print? Does it have some sort of special functionality in the console?

`End=" "`, `flush=true`: 6.46 s

Once again, why is it longer without the buffer? And this one was 13x longer?!

Edit:
I've only grown more confused:
Printing with `"end='\n'"` takes even longer than the first one! I thought all it was doing by default was appending a newline character?

Comment: *"It seems like without the middleman it should go faster."* That's not quite the right intuition. A buffer gives Python the flexibility to batch up work and print when it's most efficient. No buffer means you're telling Python "print the moment I tell you to print, I don't care if you could save it up and schedule it for a more efficient time".

Answer (score 0):

The variation in execution times occurs because of the way Pythons `print()` function handles output. When `flush=false` is set Python buffers the output grouping it into more efficient I/O operations, which leads to faster execution. While when `flush=true` is used immediate output occurs after each `print()` increasing the number of I/O operations and slowing things down. Additionally the choice between using a character (`\n`) or a space ( ) also affects performance since consoles handle text with newlines differently than continuous text. Therefore the combination of buffering and character selection contributes to the observed differences in execution times.

Comment: when the `end=` parameter is `\n` it flushes the buffer automatically. `flush=True` is only needed when the `end` parameter is changed to something else.

Comment: @S.B you are correct

Comment: or one could set PYTHONUNBUFERED env variable to True or passing `-u` to python itself to disable buffered output completely.